# jQuery select2 not working on ajax refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-select2

I have a Rails app where I'm using the `select2` JS library for selecting fields in my app.  When the initial page loads select2 is fired on any select element as it should.  But when I do an ajax/JS refresh of the partial the `select2` doesn't load and defaults to a standard dropdown selection.

Here is my example code:

**application.js**

```
$(function (){
  $(".select").select2({
        placeholder: "Select One",
        allowClear: true
  });
```

**_unassigned_calls.html.erb**

```
 <%= form_tag dispatch_call_call_path(call), :class => "dispatch-form-tag" do  %>
 <%= select_tag(:unit_ids, options_from_collection_for_select(Unit.active.order("unit_name ASC"), "id", "unit_name"), :include_blank => true, :class => 'select' )%>
 <%= button_tag 'Dispatch', class: 'btn btn-info', data: {disable_with: "<i class='icon-spinner'></i>Processing..."} %>  
 <% end %>
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div id="active">
  <%= render "assigned_calls" %>
</div>

<div id="inactive">
  <%= render "unassigned_calls" %>
</div>


<script>
  $(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
      $.getScript("/calls").fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
        window.location = "/users/sign_in?duplicate_session=true";
      });
    }, 10000);
  });
</script>
```

**index.js.erb**

```
$("#active").html("<%= escape_javascript render("assigned_calls") %>");
$("#inactive").html("<%= escape_javascript render("unassigned_calls") %>");
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
def check_concurrent_session
   if duplicate_session?
     sign_out_and_redirect(current_user)
   end
end

 def duplicate_session?
   user_signed_in? && (current_user.login_token != session[:token])
 end
```

I'm assuming based off of my code that `select2` is loaded when the DOM is loaded, but since the partial is refreshing the DOM isn't getting reloaded.

How can I fix my JS/jQuery function so that `select2` loads on a Ajax/JS refresh?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Come to find out it was a syntax error when I was adding the select2 function to `index.js.erb`  I wasn't closing the function out properly.

Here is the correct code that works:

**index.js.erb**

```
$("#active").html("<%= escape_javascript render("assigned_calls") %>");
$("#inactive").html("<%= escape_javascript render("unassigned_calls") %>");
$(".select").select2({
        placeholder: "Select One",
        allowClear: true
  });
```

Removing `window.location = "/users/sign_in?duplicate_session=true";` from **index.html.erb** got rid of the error I was receiving but was not the problem.  Removing this disabled the duplicate session message in the Devise view so I put it back in.  In the end all I needed to do was add the `.select` function to **index.js.erb** and make sure the function was closed properly.

Answer (score 0):

The `index.js.erb` is doing the refresh partial job on DOM. It changes DOM with ID `incative`. The JS event won't auto-bind for the new DOM element. So we have to rebind it, in `index.js.erb` add the following:

```
$(".select").select2({
        placeholder: "Select One",
        allowClear: true
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've updated my question to show how I'm doing the partial refresh with Ajax/JS.  In what while should I rebind `select2`?  Sorry, I'm not very good with Ajax/JS/jQuery so excuse the rookie question.

Comment: When I place this in `index.js.erb` when the partials reload after 10 seconds it redirects me to the root path instead of refreshing the partials.  Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: From your code, if the request got error, it will redirect to `/users/sign_in?duplicate_session=true`. It seems there is something wrong when doing `$.getScript("/calls")`, could you check the rails log?

Comment: When I put the code in `index.js.erb' and let the partial refresh, here is the error I receive in the dev log: `Started GET "/users/sign_in?duplicate_session=true" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-21 08:17:14 -0500
Processing by MySessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"duplicate_session"=>"true"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/home/index
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)`

Comment: I've added the `check_concurrent_session` method and the `duplicate_session?` method so you can look at it.  Not sure why adding the rebind to `index.js.erb` triggers a duplicate session.

Comment: Can you provide the log before `Started GET "/users/sign_in?duplicate_session=true" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-21 08:17:14 -0500` This request is sent after `getScript`failed.

Comment: It was too much to paste here, so I created a gist of the log before the duplicate_session error. https://gist.github.com/teknull/72cc423ae96bf4a0b467

Comment: It seems there are no errors. I think you can remove this line `window.location = "/users/sign_in?duplicate_session=true";` in index.html.erb.

Comment: I removed that line from index.html.erb and added `$(".select").select2({
        placeholder: "Select One",
        allowClear: true
  }` to index.js.erb.  Now my partials won't refresh.

Comment: I figured out the problem, it was a syntax issue with the `.select` function.  See my answer below.  It's working now.